# PHP apagar values do form se for bem sucedido

Tags: php, formulário, value

Eu gostaria que os values deste form fossem apagados se o form for submetido com sucesso, está tudo ok (não apaga) se houver algum erro mas se não houver o values continuam lá, creio que seja um erro de logica.

```
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Image<br><input type="file" name="file"></label><br><br>
    <label>Name for the image<br><input type="nameImg" name="imgName" value ="<?php if (!empty($_POST['imgName'])) { echo $_POST['imgName']; } else if (empty($database->errors())) { echo ''; } ?>"></label><br><br>
    <label>Link you wish it to have<br><input type="text" name="imgLink" value ="<?php if (!empty($_POST['imgLink'])) { echo $_POST['imgLink']; } else if (empty($database->errors())) { echo ''; } ?>"></label>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value ="Upload Image">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['imgLink'], $_POST['imgName'], $_FILES['file']['name'])) {

    $imgName = htmlentities('\'' .$_POST['imgName']. '\''); //Because of this $imgName will never be empty, we have to pass the pure input to imageInputCheck($_POST['imgName'])
    $link = htmlentities($_POST['imgLink']);

    $name = htmlentities($_FILES['file']['name']);

    $temp = explode('.', $name);
    $file_extn = strtolower(end($temp));

    $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $path = "images/" .uniqid('', true). '.' .$file_extn;



    if ($database->imageInputCheck($link, $_POST['imgName'], $name, $file_extn)) {
        $database->insertFolder($tmp_name, $path);
        $database->insertDB($path, $link, $imgName);
        echo '<br>Image upload successful.';
    }
    else {
        foreach ($database->errors() as $error) {
            echo '<div id="errors">' .$error. '</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

DB.php

```
protected $_errors = [];

public function imageInputCheck($link, $imgName, $name, $file_extn) {

        if (empty($link) && empty($name) && empty($_POST['imgName'])) {
            $this->addError('<br>Fill all<br>Don\'t be stupid');
        }
        else if (empty($link) || empty($name) || empty($_POST['imgName'])) {
            $this->addError('<br>You forgot to:<br><br>');
            if (empty($name)) {
                $this->addError('Upload an image');
            }
            if (empty($_POST['imgName'])) {
                $this->addError('Give a name to your image');
            }
            if (empty($link)) {
                $this->addError('Give a link to your image');
            }
        }

        else if (($file_extn == 'jpg' || $file_extn == 'png' || $file_extn == 'tif' || $file_extn == 'gif' || $file_extn == 'jpeg') && strlen($imgName) <= 60) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            $this->addError('<br>Couldn\'t upload file to database or the folder, make sure it\'s an image.<br>Make sure it\'s name is under 60 characters');
        }
        return false;
    }

private function addError($error) {
        $this->_errors[] = $error;
    }

    public function errors() {
        return $this->_errors;
    }
```

Comment: Tens de, depois de gravar na BD, de libertar as variáveis.

Comment: Como? desculpe a minha ignorância

Answer (score 1):

No PHP, não há uma forma efetiva de dar um unset no $_POST como um todo. Você até pode dar um unset diretamente nas chaves que utilizou, por exemplo:

```
unset($_POST['imgName']);
unset($_POST['imgLink']);
...
```

Mas, de qualquer forma, a única solução efetiva e segura é fazer um reenvio da página, ou, melhor ainda, executar o processamento em um arquivo separado (indicado no parâmetro "action" da tag form) e redirecionar de volta para a página ao término....

```
header('location:caminho/pagina-de-volta.php');
```

Em caso de erros, você pode utilizar sessões ou query strings para sinalizar o problema, recuperar valores no formulário, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Prezado Miguel, acho relevante eliminar a lógica do Html, separando em coisas distintas:

```
<?php
$imgName = isset($_POST['imgName']) ? $_POST['imgName'] : ""; 
$imgLink = isset($_POST['imgLink']) ? $_POST['imgLink'] : "";
?>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Image<br></label>
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <br><br>
    <label for='nameImg'>Name for the image</label>
    <input type="nameImg" name="imgName" value ="<?php echo $imgName ?>">
    <br><br>
    <label for="imgLink">Link you wish it to have</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="imgLink" value ="<?php echo $imgLink ?>">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value ="Upload Image">
</form>
```

E dentro do laço que valida e salva:

```
if ($database->imageInputCheck($link, $_POST['imgName'], $name, $file_extn)) {
    $database->insertFolder($tmp_name, $path);
    $database->insertDB($path, $link, $imgName);
    unset($_POST);
    echo '<br>Image upload successful.';
}
```

Caso esteja tudo certo, vai eliminar as variáveis do post, e quando voltar ao form, as atribuições condicionais irão setar os values com `" "`.

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: Não é o autofill do navegador que está ativado?
Tem navegadores que salvam formulários...

Comment: Nop, acabei de testar

Comment: Engraçado, simulei aqui, e funcionou, será que está salvando e no caso chegando até este ponto do `unset`? Coloque alguns `echo`'s com mensagens como salvou, erro, etc em alguns pontos, e veja para onde está indo a lógica.

Comment: Sim, já tentei tudo o que me disseste... Mas se definir as vars '$imgName' e '$imgLink' como disseste dá-me o erro: "undifined var...." por isso deixei as condições no field do value inclusive tentei lá dentro: <?php if (!empty($_POST['imgName'])) { echo $_POST['imgName']; } else if (empty($database->errors())) { unset($_POST[imgName]); }

Comment: Só uma coisa quando dizes "autofill" é no html, "autocomplete" no input certo"?

Comment: Preenchimento automático... alguns navegadores tem esta função, mas não sei se deveria ser ativada, pois o `$_POST` vazio setaria uma string vazia no campo. Por isso, acho que algo não está sendo validado, você checou se realmente está salvando e chegando no unset? Ele exibe o `echo` que tem após o unset?

Comment: Verdade, vou atualizar a resposta, trocando o empty por isset, o erro ocorre, pois o unset elimina o $_POST, só percebo outra coisa, se ocorrer do usuário pressionar `F5` o form reenvia novamente, e para isso não ocorrer, teria de aplicar sessão na sua app.

Comment: Não aconselho fazer validação dentro do HTML, puxando o objeto `$database`, isso não pertence a visualização, deveria ser verificado somente dentro das funções no arquivo `db.php`.
Por isso eliminei, e refiz o form da forma que coloquei na resposta, tratando apenas com a global `$_POST`.

Comment: Sim o echo 'image upload success' acontece

Comment: Tentou com a alteração do `!empty()` pelo `isset()`?